# Replace [DEGREE] in column data with its symbol in oracle

Tags: oracle, extended-ascii

I have a column which contains text like [DEG],[MICRO],[PHASE].
I want to replace it with their symbols in oracle. 
My current version of oracle in 11g.
Below link contains the complete list of replacements.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqdCw.png

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your database character set?

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET - AL32UTF8

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to see your image. But here is what you could to to translate the occurrences of `[DEG]`,`[MICRO]`,`[PHASE]` by using Oracle [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) functions (which are limited):

Say `v_txt` contains the text you want to change.

```
declare 
  v_txt varchar2(4000) := '[]titi;[DEG],[MICRO],[PHASE],[DEG]toto ';
  v_key varchar2(100) := '';
  v_n number:=0;
begin
    for x in (select     'DEG' key, CHR(11*16+0 )val from dual  ---  DEG UNICODE is B0
        union all select 'MICRO'  , CHR(11*16+5 )    from dual  ---  MICRO UNICODE is B5
        union all select 'PHASE'  , CHR(13*16+14)    from dual  ---  THORN UNICODE is B5
        -- 'PHASE' was not found here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/... I assumed "THORN" letter instead
    )
    loop
        -- check if text contains key:
        select count(1) into v_n 
          from (select v_txt t from dual) 
         where t like '%['||x.key||']%' ;
        while (v_n>0) loop
          -- replace key with value in text
          select regexp_replace(my_text,'(.*)\['||x.key||'\](.*)' ,'\1'||x.val||'\2') 
            into v_txt 
            from (select v_txt my_text from dual);
          -- check if key still there
          select count(1) into v_n 
            from (select v_txt t from dual) 
           where t like '%['||x.key||']%' ;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_txt);
end;
```

/

We start by defining a (key,val) table on which we loop, and for each couple we use a while loop as long as the text we want to replace contains the key value.

Beware: it is easy to understand, but it might not be the most effective way.

### To use it on a whole column of data:

You can easily make a function from the above:

```
create or replace function f (p_txt varchar2) return varchar2   
is
    v_txt varchar2(4000) := p_txt;
    ...
begin
    ...
    return v_txt;
end f;
/
```

Then `SELECT` on the whole column:

```
SELECT f(my_col) FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can use `unistr('\00b5')` function instead of `CHR(11*16+5 ) `

Comment: I used **unistr('\00b5')** and it worked fine. Thanks